# Ruby / Rails - AJAX pagination of nested resources - How do I determine the parent resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, pagination, nested-resources

My model has `Posts`, `Users`, and `Comments`. Users can leave Comments on/about Posts.
Every Comment belongs to a User and a Post.
Therefore, the Comment model has a `user_id` field and a `post_id` field.

When viewing a `Post`, I want to paginate through that Post's comments.
When viewing a `User`, I want to paginate through that User's comments.
I want to paginate using AJAX (via the Kaminari gem).

I have my nested routes set up for both.

On the Post, the URL being hit is `http://localhost:3000/posts/{:id}/comments?page={page_number}`
On the User, the URL being hit is `http://localhost:3000/users/{:id}/comments?page={page_number}`

Both URLs are hitting the index action of the Comments controller.

My question is this: inside the `index` action, how do I determine if the `{:id}` provided is a `user_id` or a `post_id` so I can retrieve the desired comments.

Comment: You can check it with regexp on request.env["HTTP_REFERRER"] for example. If there is users match so :id belongs to user vise versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for `params[:user_id]` and `params[:post_id]` in your Comments controller:

```
if params[:user_id]
  #call came from /users/ url
elsif params[:post_id]
  #call came from /posts/ url
else
  #call came from some other url
end
```

Comment: These parent resource id's are not there or this appears to not be true in Rails 4, at least in the app I have built.

Answer (score 0):

I like the Ryan Bates' way

```
class CommentsController
  before_action :load_commentable

  def index
    @comments = @commentable.comments.page(params[:page])
  end

  private

    def load_commentable
      klass = [Post, User].detect { |c| params["#{c.name.underscore}_id"] }
      @commentable = klass.find(params["#{klass.name.underscore}_id"])
    end
end
```